# Encoding ISO 8859-1 to display Spanish text correctly in UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, ios6.1, tbxml

I am facing problem in converting the Spanish text that is fetched from the service in

correct format. Server side they are encoding with `ISO-8859-1`. It is a xml service. In my

iOS7 app, I am using `TBXml` parser to parse the data. The code is:

```
NSString *XMLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlString encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:nil];

TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLString:XMLString];
```

I am parsing this data, but the when there are Spanish characters like "*BEBÉS Y*" the my

string will be "*BEB…S Y*" . And "*øPor quÈ albergamos a alborotadores?*" instead of "*¿Por qué 
albergamos a alborotadores?*" . Please help

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Are you sure it's actually ISO-8859-1 encoding?  You can switch to the method `[NSString -initWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:]` to have it try to automatically detect the encoding (it will report back to you what it used.)

Comment: @AaronBrager It would be better to download binary and let the XML parser decide on the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the XML data as binary (`NSData`) and let the parser handle the encoding.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;
TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithXMLData:data error:&error];
```

Note the XML should have the content encoding as the first line so there is no need to specify an encoding in code.

Comment: Thank you. My TBXml parser encoding with "NSUTF8StringEncoding" should i replace with "NSISOLatin1StringEncoding" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with NSUTF8StringEncoding

```
NSString *XMLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLString:XMLString];
```

UPDATE:

```
NSData *dataContent = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlString];
NSString *XMLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataContent encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLString:XMLString];
```

UPDATE 2: Try with data initialization

```
NSData *dataContent = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlString];

TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLData:XMLString];
```

Comment: I used that, but this time the data itself is empty

Comment: Thank you friend. NSData *dataContent = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlString];